# How to split qbyteArray containing jpg images or iterate about it

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on an app with c++,Qt and Qt Creator where amongst others the user can choose multiple images (.jpg files), display it and store it in a sqlite database as blob

```
QStringList pfad = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this, tr("Bilddateien auswählen"),
                        QDir::homePath(), tr("Bilddateien(*.png *.jpg *.bmp"));

QByteArray Foto::foto_daten(const QStringList dateiPfad)
{
    //QStringList const dateiPfad = foto_get();
    QByteArray fotoDaten;
    for (int i = 0; i < dateiPfad.size(); i++)
    {
        QString dateiName = dateiPfad[i];
        QFile file(dateiName);
        file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        QByteArray byteArray = file.readAll();
        fotoDaten.append(byteArray + '$');
    }
    return fotoDaten;
}
```

(Here "pfad" is the variable passed to method "foto_daten" as argument;
return value is used for storage in the database as blob datatype and I added '$' as a separator)
So long no problem.
I can also go the opposite way: Get the blob value out of the database via Select statemant, convert it to a QByteArray object and display it to a TableView.

```
QByteArray fotoByte;
fotoByte = query_combo.value("kon_fotoDaten").toByteArray();
if (!fotoByte.isNull())
{
    QPixmap outPixmap = QPixmap();
    outPixmap.loadFromData( fotoByte );
    int w = ui->labelFotoZeigen->width();
    int h = 300;

    ui->labelFotoZeigen->setPixmap(outPixmap);
    ui->labelFotoZeigen->setPixmap(outPixmap.scaled(w, h, Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
}
```

My problem is:
If I stored maybe 3 images as one blob in the database (via append method to a QByteArray object)
I get only the first image back of the stored three to display.
I proved if really three images are stored via size() method and yes I get different sizes storing only one or three images.

I tried QList split method but no success, I got tens of splits. I tried also several seperators, the same.
Is there a possibility to get each single image back? Split with a special seperator or a iterate method on QByteArray object?

Comment: You're assuming your '$' separators will be the only '$' characters present in the data -- that's not a valid assumption.  You need to rethink the way in which you encode multiple jpegs in a single `QByteArray`/blob.  Try prepending each set of jpeg data with its size or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

The separator is ambiguous, as it is not guaranteed to not be present in the data. I suggest you use [QDataStream](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdatastream.html) to serialize QByteArray's. You can serialize and deserialize without ambiguity most Qt types, including QByteArray's.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion. I decided to go another way: I created a directory in the program folder (so I have a fixed certain path to it)  where I can save the images. Only the titles are stored in the database. It seems to work well. Another advantage: It keeps the database lean.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).